# Create multiple (sub) registry keys in powershell

Tags: powershell, registry

```
$Path = "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\Test1\Test2\Test3\Test4"
New-Item -Path $Path
```

Getting below error

```
New-Item : The registry key at the specified path does not exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form of the registry path is wrong.
Use the following:

```
$Path = "HKLM:\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\Test1\Test2\Test3\Test4"
New-item -Path $Path -Force
```

As i see you are creating more than one sub dir, thats why you will need -Force switch.
Using reg dirs in powerhsell

Hkey local machine = HKLM
Hkey current user = HKCU
Etc.

Comment: We can use the both method in the registry path

Comment: -Force is creating the subfolders also. Thanks!!